# How to create a FOR where every 10 correct questions raise a level

Tags: java, android

I have to find the method where every 10 correct questions raise 1 level and so on.

void updateScoreAndLevel(int answerGiven){

```
    if(isCorrect(answerGiven)) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i = i + 100) {
            currentScore = currentScore + 100;
        }
        for (int i = 10; i <= currentScore; i++) {
            currentLevel = currentLevel + i;
        }

    }else{
        currentScore = currentScore - 50;
        currentLevel = currentLevel ;
    }
```

I hope that every 10 correct questions go up one level but it does not give me

Comment: it's android studio but it would not let me place the tag I was asking for a higher level in my profile @str

Comment: How about this?: Declare a counter variable before your other code (like `int counter = 0`), and add 1 to this variable each time there is a correct answer. Repeatedly test whether the counter has reached 10, and when it has, you can change the level and reset counter to zero.

Comment: I do not understand, sir @Cat

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isCorrect) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i = i + 100) {
            currentScore = currentScore + 100;
            amountCorrect + 1;
        }
        for (int i = 10; i <= currentScore; i++) {
            currentLevel = currentLevel + i;
        }

    }else{
        currentScore = currentScore - 50;
        currentLevel = currentLevel ;
    }

    if(amountCorrect % 10 == 1){
        currentLevel + 1;
    }
```

Something like this i think. You can add a amountCorrect interger. Which goes up every time the player get's it right. If he get's it wrong you can lower it (if you want to)

the % ,aka the modulo (not good with names), will check if the player has 10 or more answers correct and adds a level. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: The (currentlevel + 1) throws it at me as an errorand the name of my variable to each correct question is correctanswer @Quintin

Comment: could you elaboratie a little bit? What does the error say exactly?

Comment: the amount correct is not defined I think I use the name of the variable is correct to find the correct question. It tells me that the variable is not established, I'm working on android studio

Comment: It means you need to declare the variable. So you need to declare the interger amountCorrect.

So in your program you need to place a line which declare the variable amountCorrect like you declared the intergers currentScore and currentLevel

Comment: If the answer is correct, the score and level must be increased. The score is increased by 100 if the answer is correct and decreases by 50 if it is incorrect. The level is increased every 10 correct questions, regardless of whether there are incorrect in the meantime. Implement a method that does this and call it updateScore ().That is the question to the problem

Comment: As Cat said all you need to do in that case is make a variable counter which keeps track of how many times a player has answered correctly.

Useing an if statement you can check if the amount is 10. In code that would be.

    if (amountCorrect == 10){
        currentLevel += 1;
        amountCorrect = 0
    }

Should be pretty clear on how you should do it. If not i can't help you any further as i don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: if (amountCorrect == 10){ currentLevel += 1; amountCorrect = 0 } This one yes. This will be my last update. Cat has given you a clear answer and i already gave you the code needed to do it. If you still can't figure it out with this information i can't help you further.

Comment: Please can you write it to me as a code like you did before

Answer (score 0):

Here is a longer example of what I meant in my comment (Sorry if my syntax is off, but I haven't written Java in years):

```
// Defines global variables (including parallel arrays of questions/answers)
String[] questions = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
String[] answers = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
int score = 0;
int level = 1;
int counter = 0;

// Loops through all questions
for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
  String nextQuestion = questions[i];

  // (You should show nextQuestion to the user and get their answer here...)
  // (Eg: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)
  String answer = answers[i]; // This demo assumes that the user answers correctly

  // Checks if answer is correct, and updates variables accordingly
  if(answer == answers[i]){
    // Correct answer increases score and counter (and sometimes level)
    score = score + 100;
    counter = counter + 1;
    // After 3 correct answers, changes level and resets counter
    if(counter == 3){
      level = level + 1;
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  else{
    // Incorrect answer decreases score
    score = score - 50;
  }
}
```